# Recalculate Variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm not sure how to ask/search this question, been crawling around stack overflow for some time now - so will try my best here.

Its all surrounding data binding, and a chart being refreshed once data is updated without me having to refresh the entire page.

So i have several functions that use 3 variables.

Say:

```
var vis = ///some value;
var partition = ///some value;
var arc = ///some value;
```

and

```
function action1() {
  //some business using one/more of the variables above
}

function action2(){
   //some business using one/more of the variables above
}
```

Now when the model gets updated I can easily call the functions action1 and action2 however I also want the variables to be 'recalculated' with the new model data.

I was thinking I could place them in a function however the scope won't be visible to `action1` and `action2`.

Any suggestions on what I can do.

Hope thats clear.

Thanks.

Comment: Store them in a factory, then bind the factory.getVariable() calls to scope.

Comment: You can also use events ($emit / $broadcast) - but it's hard to understand the prefered solution with the provided information

Comment: Factory sounds like an idea - however how will it get 'recalculated' each time? So i guess i declare it like `.factory('testFactory', function(){ var vis = //some magic} )` then use it like `testFactory.vis`?

Comment: more like, `factory.getVis` could return `vis`, while `factory.action1` recalculates `vis` (or returns it, too). Then you can use it consistently in other controllers.